# What is the pattern called where you move a class' static properties to a separate class?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, object-oriented-design

Personally, I call this the Blueprint Pattern; however, I am sure someone else must have already named it. Static members, are in most cases, not a good thing. In languages such as C# and Java, they remove polymorphism and encourage poor class design. However, many times, there are properties that all instances share.

```
//Original class where shared properties are static
class StandardHenchman
{
    static int MaxHealth;
    static int Speed;
    int CurrentHealth;
    int X;
    int Y;
}

//More maintainable and flexible design 
class NPCType
{
    int MaxHealth;
    int Speed;
}

class NPC
{
   NPCType Type;
   int CurrentHealth;
   int X;
   int Y;
}

henchman1 = new NPC();
henchman1.Type = standardHenchman;
henchman2 = new NPC();
henchman2.Type = standardHenchman;
```

It is possible to just duplicate the shared values in every instance, but I think that also comes with problems.

What is the pattern called where you declare shared/static members with composition?

Comment: This is not a *pattern*, it is a *refactoring*. And since it I cannot find it in  [Fowler' catalog](https://refactoring.com/catalog/), I doubt there is a broadly accepted term for this transformation.

Comment: Well, is there a name for if you just do it that way initially? If not, I am just going to keep calling it the blueprint pattern

Comment: Wow, looking at the down votes, people love their static members :D

Comment: Your refactoring doesn't have the same semantics as the original (your henchmen no longer share the same MaxHealth and Speed), so it's not really a refactoring either, but merely a rewrite.  In other news, "Blueprint" doesn't seem like a very good name for this.

Comment: Curious as to why you don't like that name? What would you call it?

Comment: Not every tiny code transformation has a special name (or needs one). I would call it 1. "creation of a new type which bundles two scalar values" followed by 2. "replacing a static variable by a non-static one". Note you are doing two unrelated things here, not just one.

Comment: I agree Doc, but I think this one does. In many CS programs, we are taught to put shared members in static members. I think for some people, this is a radical departure to how they normally think about OO design.

Comment: What purpose does this "radical departure" serve, exactly?

Comment: 1. It enables polymorphism. Doing the same with every class, you would have to redeclare it each time, or have it invariant in an abstract base class
2. it allows mutability, what if you want to turn your standardhenchman into a raginghulkhenchman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's similar to the [Flyweight pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight) in that "the object is divided into two pieces: the state-dependent (extrinsic) part, and the state-independent (intrinsic) part. "

But it is different in that the motivation behind Flyweight is saving memory (not code reuse) when instantiating **a lot of objects**. It does so by separating the part that is common to all instances in a separate class, including behavior, not necessarily because they are static. Also Flyweight involves a factory and caching of objects.

I would say it is a simple version of Flyweight albeit, of course, not "the" Flyweight.

Comment: I looked more into flyweight, and this is best name for it, I don't think the Wikipedia article makes it as clear as others.

Comment: In java generally you 'code to interfaces'. And the interface would hold the static data, not the implementation.